# Crear un EXE desde un archivo Python con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

La cosa es que tengo un directorio donde tengo diferentes archivos python con una estructura similar a la siguiente

Carpeta
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L_____|apps 
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎| ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L______ ini__.py
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎| ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L____|"Carpeta sript1"
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎| ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L____|"Carpeta sript2"
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L_____|modules 
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎| ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L____|"db.py"
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎| ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎  ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎‏‏‎L____|"pdf.py"
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L_____|Config.py 
‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎ ‍‍‍‍‍‎ ‏‏‎‎ ‏‏‎L_____|run.py

Donde run es el archivo que ejecuta el codigo pero que necesita de los codigos y archivos que se encuentran dentro de las carpetas app,modules y config.py

Cuando creo el archivo .EXE con pyinstaller no me da ningun error, es mas todo bien hasta que lo ejecuto que me da lo siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "apps\GT01\gt01.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "modules\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "modules\pdf.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules.db'
```

yo la creación del EXE lo he hecho tanto dentro de un entorno virtual como fuera ambos he usado el mismo comando:

```
pyinstaller.exe .\app.spec
```

la configuración del archivo .spec es la siguiente:

```
block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['app.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Nueva carpeta\\carpeta'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='Ejecutable',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

No se si el problema es que no estoy importando todo, o que me falta alguna configuracion o cual es...

Por supuesto el proyecto funciona perfectamente cuando lo ejecuto usando python con el comando:

```
python ./app.py
```

Comment: has probado `pyinstaller --onefile app.py` para dejar todo en un solo archivo?
echa un vistaso a la documentoacion https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html

Comment: @John Sii y es el error que me sale :(

Comment: pero allí esta el error, agrega hiddenimports=["tus modulos", "otros modulos"], en tu spec, pasa que no los importa pordefault, debes indicarselo

Comment: @John debería de importar todos los archivos .py o la carpeta?

Comment: Solo los que dependan de tu proyecto y no se carguen al inicio, o los que te acuse que no encuentra.